# How to split string in a list and compare each word with a set of key words

Tags: python, string, python-2.7

i have a list with contents like :-

```
for 30 days
for 40 working days
for 20 weeks
for 2 months
```

i want to split each sentence and compare with set of keywords :-

```
day
week
month
year
```

if the keyword `'days'` is present in the string then i want to multiply the number in that string with `'1'`. if the keyword `'month'` is present then multiply the number in that string with `'30'` and so on... i am new to python so please!

**my code**

```
   with open("test_term.csv", "rb") as file1:
        reader = csv.reader(file1)
        extractedlist = list(reader)
        #print extractedlist
def split_line(text):
    # split the text
    words = text[0].split(' ')
    # for each word in the line:
    new_list = []
    for word in words:
        #print word
        #print w2n.word_to_num(word)
        conversion = w2n.word_to_num(word)
        if isinstance(conversion, (int,long)):
            #print conversion
            new_list.append(conversion)            

        else:
            new_list.append(word)


    return new_list

for extraRow in extractedlist:
    worn = split_line(extraRow)
    keywords = {"day":1,"days":1,"year":365,"years":365,"week":7,"weeks":7,"month":30,"months":30}
    #for s in worn:
     #   splitted_string = s.split(' ')
    interesting_words = worn[2:]
    mult = 1
    for k,v in keywords.iteritems():
        for word in interesting_words :
            mult = v
            break
        result = mult*worn[1]
        print result
```

right now i have only one input string `for thirty working days`here the `'thirty'` is being converted to `'30'` so in worn we have `'for thirty working days'`
the output is :-

```
210  
900  
10950
900  
210  
10950
30   
30
```

but the output i expect is 30*1 ie, `'30'`

Comment: Are the contents really like that or can there be more text on the left/right side?

Comment: Check [this demo](https://ideone.com/8MHDFv).

Comment: I've just posted an answer that works for me (I've tried it out in my computer)

Comment: @javidgon...could you please check the code i have posted in the question and update your answer accordingly?...thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could create a dictionnary first :
`dictionnary = {"day":1, "month":30 ... }`

with a splitted string like :

```
splitted_string = ["for", 30, "working", "days"]
interesting_words = splitted_string[2:] # ["working", "days"]
```

from there, you could just get the element "days" and find the corresponding element in your dictionnary. Once the element is find, we just get the value and break the loop.

```
mult = 1
for k,v in dictionnary.iteritems():
    for word in interesting_words :
        if k in word :
            mult = v
            break
```

You can finally perfrom your operation :

```
result = mult*splitted_string[1] #30
```

Comment: splitted_string = worn.split(' ') ... gives an AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split' ... how do i fix it?

Comment: That means that worn is already a list and not a string. >>> s = "for 30 days"
>>> s.split(' ') gives you : 
['for', '30', 'days']

Comment: how do i split worn...the reason being, this is just a part of the code im writing worn actually has been got after another whole lot of operations...is there anyway i can split string in worn one by one...the list is in worn and i understand worn itself is a list..

Comment: worn should already be a list with your elements, you can print it to be sure.

Comment: ['for', 30, 'working', 'days'] is the output for print worn

Comment: I edit my post with your new infos. You can just consider that what's interesting is before '30' so you could create a new list with just what's after. for each word in each interesting_words, you check if you have a match.

Comment: but how did you get splitted_string when its giving that error?

Comment: splitted_string is actually your "worn" variable

Comment: can you please check the edit i made in my question...i have added he output i am getting now and the changes i have made to the code as per your answer...

Comment: you forget the if statement before "mult = v"

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv     # imports the csv module

f = open('file.csv', 'rb') # opens the csv file
results = []
try:
    reader = csv.reader(f)  # creates the reader object
    for row in reader:   # iterates the rows of the file in orders
        l = row[0].split(' ')
        if 'day' in l[2]:
            l[1] = int(l[1]) * 1
        elif 'working' in l[2]:
            if len(l) > 3  and 'day' in l[3]:
                l[1] = int(l[1]) * 1
        elif 'week' in l[2]:
            l[1] = int(l[1]) * 7
        elif 'month' in l[2]:
            l[1] = int(l[1]) * 30
        elif 'year' in l[2]:
            l[1] = int(l[1]) * 365
        results.append(l)

finally:
    print results
    f.close()      # closing
```

Answer (score 0):

If your data are in a list, you can just iterate over it. Then split each string and search a keyword at the end of the list (`'day' in ' '.join(data_split[2:])`):

```
data = ['for 30 days',
    'for 40 working days',
    'for 20 weeks',
    'for 2 months']

for d in data:
    data_split = d.split(' ')
    if 'day' in ' '.join(data_split[2:]):
        print(int(data_split[1]))
    elif 'month' in ' '.join(data_split[2:]):
        print(int(data_split[1]) * 30)
```